# What is the if-else indentation when we use "break" in the if block?(in Python)

Tags: python

I ran the following code and there is no problem.

```
for i in range(1,10):
  if i%5 == 0: break
  print(i)
else:
  print("for else")
```

But I want to know why a SyntaxError occurs when if block and else block are aligned?
I mean the following code that gives an error during execution.

```
for i in range(1,10):
  if i%5 == 0: break
  print(i)
  else:
  print("for else")
```

Comment: If the first code, the `else` is attached to the `for`. In the second code, it is attached to nothing. Without meaningful indentation, it makes no sense.

Comment: Single-line if-statements must have the else on the very next line

Comment: That's a for-else, not an if-else.

Comment: You should fix the `else:` indentation first (one indentation to the left), it must be belong to for loop if you want to print `for else` string.

Comment: Maybe it is easier for you to read if you would make 4-chars indention and not 2-chars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `if` could be followed *immediately* by an `else:` but you have a `print` between them.

It may be clearer if you reformat this with consistent indentation. I'm leaving out the `print` to illustrate two different options.

```py
for i in range(1,10):
  if i%5 == 0:
      break
  else:
      print("for else")
```

Here, the `else:` is taken if the `if` condition is false, each time the loop is executed.

```py
for i in range(1,10):
  if i%5 == 0:
      break
else:
  print("for else")
```

Here, the `else:` belongs to the `for`, and is taken when you exit the `for` loop if its body was never executed completely.